# Differential forms, PDE's and Élie Cartan

Tags: foliations, dg.differential-geometry, reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Hello everybody, I would like to know about the work of Élie Cartan of PDE's that relate to the theory of foliations and differential forms.

I am interested in the subject and will be happy to receive basic references on the subject (articles) as well as explanations on the importance of the subject in mathematics today.

Comment: I'm wondering if this question is a bit overbroad. (See the FAQ.) Also I am not sure why the OP wanted a dynamical-systems tag on this question. For the time being I'll leave it there. 

Comment: A starting point may be section 2 of http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183516693

Comment: I was going to suggest the book by Bryant, Chern, ... on *Exterior Differential Systems*, which is available for free from the MSRI: http://www.msri.org/communications/books/Book18/MSRI-v18-Bryant-Chern-et-al.pdf

Comment: Ivey and Landsberg, cartan for beginners

Comment: Thanks Wong,  Yang and Figueroa! It is a good start for my 
bibliographic research

Comment: I would also recommend the book "Symmetries and conservation laws in equations of mathematical physics" by Vinogradov et. al. There are several other books from this group of authors.

Comment: I wrote up some of my lectures: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.09697.pdf

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Robert Bryant is the reigning expert on this. An excellent book on the subject (later than the one mentioned) is:
Exterior Differential Systems and Euler-Lagrange Partial Differential Equations, Chicago Lectures in Mathematics (2003), University of Chicago Press (vii+213 pages, ISBN: 0-226-07794-2.) by
R. Bryant, Phillip Griffiths and Dan Grossmann.

I just recalled, Bryant has a very nice set of nine introductory lectures on the subject. It may be just what you are looking for! They are available online here:

https://services.math.duke.edu/~bryant/Introduction_to_EDS.pdf

Comment: A preliminary version of the book is available on the arXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/math.DG/0207039

Comment: Hi, I made the address of the nine lectures a genuine link. Will.

Answer (score 1):

Another highly readable reference for this material is the book *[Equivalence, Invariants and Symmetry](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/equivalence-invariants-and-symmetry/47AF645200DFC05F59D0235A39161903)* by Peter Olver.